# A summary on a dataframe show me the majors values for a character field. When I apply a substr on it : I receive "useless" information instead

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in *R* language.

I have loaded an *Excel* sheet into a dataframe.
A summary show me these informations :

```
summary(dat)

      APE                                                          LIBELLE       EFFECTIF  
 8110Z  :638   Activités combinées de soutien lié aux bâtiments        :638   1,5    :664  
 2370Z  :  8   Commerce de gros de bois et de matériaux de construction:  8   4      : 57  
 4511Z  :  8   Commerce de voitures et de véhicules automobiles légers :  8   34,5   : 37  
 4673A  :  8   Hôtels et hébergement similaire                         :  8   14,5   : 36  
 5510Z  :  8   Taille, façonnage et finissage de pierres               :  8   7,5    : 24  
 2363Z  :  6   Fabrication de béton prêt à l'emploi                    :  6   74,5   : 17  
 (Other):181   (Other)                                                 :181   (Other): 22
```

The `APE` code (that I think is now the european `NACE` code but the field has an old name) is too detailed with five characters. I execute this statement to take only its two first characters into account :

```
dat$APE <- substr(dat$APE, 1, 2)
```

Then, the `summary` command doesn't show me the result I expected :

```
summary(dat)

 APE                                                                LIBELLE       EFFECTIF  
 Length:857         Activités combinées de soutien lié aux bâtiments        :638   1,5    :664  
 Class :character   Commerce de gros de bois et de matériaux de construction:  8   4      : 57  
 Mode  :character   Commerce de voitures et de véhicules automobiles légers :  8   34,5   : 37  
                    Hôtels et hébergement similaire                         :  8   14,5   : 36  
                    Taille, façonnage et finissage de pierres               :  8   7,5    : 24  
                    Fabrication de béton prêt à l'emploi                    :  6   74,5   : 17  
                    (Other)                                                 :181   (Other): 22
```

I was expecting 23, 45, 46, 55, 81... in the APE column.

I don't figure where the problem may come from, as when I do an `head` command, everything seems fine.

```
head(dat)

  APE                                                           LIBELLE EFFECTIF
1  02                                           Exploitation forestière        4
2  08 Extraction pierres ornement. construc. calcaire industriel, gypse     14,5
3  08        Exploit gravieres & sablieres, extraction argiles & kaolin     34,5
4  10             Préparation industrielle de produits à base de viande        4
5  10             Préparation industrielle de produits à base de viande      7,5
6  10                          Transformation et conservation de fruits     34,5
```

Regards,

Comment: I bet your original column is a `factor`. `substr` turns it into a character. You might want to apply `substr` on the factor `levels`.

Comment: @Roland, your comment is the good one. When I sat `dat$APE <- as.factor(substr(dat$APE, 1, 2))` it worked well. If you take the time to copy paste your comment into a response to my question, I will mark it as the answer for it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Roland thanks for your good answer.

```r
dat$APE <- as.factor(substr(dat$APE, 1, 2))
```

succeeded in converting a String to a factor with corrected my problem.